# SensorEventListener doesn't seems running. How to get the sensor value?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

I'm testing android wear sensor for future implementations. My goal is to get the heart rate value, and display it in my MainActivity. So I've implemented a `SensorHelper class`:

```
import static android.content.Context.SENSOR_SERVICE;

public class SensorHelper implements SensorEventListener {

    private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private final Sensor mHeartRate;
    public String sensorValue = "deafult";

    public SensorHelper() {
        Log.i("SENSOR", "SENSOR CONSTRUCTOR");
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) MyApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mHeartRate = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
            String msg = "" + (int)event.values[0];
            this.sensorValue = msg;
            Log.d("SENSOR", msg);
        }
        else
            this.sensorValue = "unable to read value";
            Log.d("SENSOR", "Unknown sensor type");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
}
```

As far as I know, the `onSensorChanged` function should be called, every time the heart rate is changing. In this function, I'm updating the `sensorValue` variable.

In the `MainActivity.class`, I created a button to refresh a `TextView` by assigning the `Sensorhelper.sensorValue`'s value to it:

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

    private Button refreshButton;
    private TextView mTextView;
    SensorHelper sensorHelper;

    private View.OnClickListener refreshListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("refresh");
            mTextView.setText(sensorHelper.sensorValue);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sensorHelper = new SensorHelper();

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        refreshButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_refresh);
        refreshButton.setOnClickListener(refreshListener);

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled();
    }
}
```

I added the `BODY_SENSORS` permission. The problem is, that the `TextView` always stays on "default", and the button doesn't refreshing the value. I think I'm missing something from the SensorHelper implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the call to register the listener for getting new values.

In your `SensorHelper` constructor add `mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRate, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);`

```
public SensorHelper() {
    Log.i("SENSOR", "SENSOR CONSTRUCTOR");
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) MyApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mHeartRate = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRate, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

Remember to call `mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);` when you don't need the sensor any more.

Check out [SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager) documentation for more details.